# grouping and summarizing a text file in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this example:

example:

```
chr12   58146000    58146050    79  chr12   58145961    58146075    CDK4
chr12   58146050    58146075    81  chr12   58145961    58146075    CDK4
chr12   69082750    69082800    57  chr12   69082741    69082833    NUP107
chr12   99038450    99038479    81  chr12   99038300    99038479    IKBIP
chr12   104680862   104680887   512 chr12   104680862   104680887   TXNRD1
chr12   104682708   104682750   134 chr12   104682708   104682818   TXNRD1
```

I want to group them based on column 8 and sum the values of column 4 which belong the same group and the results would be a tab separated file with 2 columns. the first column is the numbers that are made after summation(from 4th column) and the 2nd column is the group name (from 8th column). I tried the following code but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

```
cut -d'\t' -f 8 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print sum($4), $8 }' infile > outfile
```

here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
160 CDK4
57  NUP107
81  IKBIP
646 TXNRD1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{sum[$8]+=$4} END{for (grp in sum) print sum[grp], grp}' file
81      IKBIP
57      NUP107
646     TXNRD1
160     CDK4
```

Comment: nit: Question specifies "tab separated file" as output, so I would recommend `awk ... OFS=\\t` rather than piping to `column -t`

Comment: Eventually add `| sort -k2` to have the same order as what was requested in the question, or maybe `asorti`? in GNU context.

Comment: @Allan sorting the output would not produce the order shown in the question. If the OP wants a specific output order it'd probably be the same order as input rather than sorting the output and that'd be trivial to do within the awk script, again **IF** necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) instead of awk:

```
$ datamash -s groupby 8 sum 4 < data.tsv | datamash reverse
160 CDK4
81  IKBIP
57  NUP107
646 TXNRD1
```

This assumes the columns in the input file are also tab separated. If it's not, add `-W` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `perl`

```
 perl -lane ' $kv{$F[7]}+=$F[3]; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_\t$kv{$_}" }} '
```

using the given inputs

```
$ cat elly.txt
chr12   58146000    58146050    79  chr12   58145961    58146075    CDK4
chr12   58146050    58146075    81  chr12   58145961    58146075    CDK4
chr12   69082750    69082800    57  chr12   69082741    69082833    NUP107
chr12   99038450    99038479    81  chr12   99038300    99038479    IKBIP
chr12   104680862   104680887   512 chr12   104680862   104680887   TXNRD1
chr12   104682708   104682750   134 chr12   104682708   104682818   TXNRD1

$ perl -lane ' $kv{$F[7]}+=$F[3]; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_\t$kv{$_}" }} ' elly.txt
NUP107  57
TXNRD1  646
IKBIP   81
CDK4    160

$
```